# Locked Y axis rotation is also rotating on Z

Tags: modeling

I'm new to blender

How can i get a Z axis only rotation?

I'm trying to make a mug with a handle and when I lock rotation on the y axis I get slight amounts of rotation on Z also; resulting in the handle spiraling as shown below.

[image: End result]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the image it looks like the rotation is normal but your handle is not centered on the mug and that's causing it to look warped.

Comment: Can't any side be the center?

Comment: Yup that was it. The face wasn't centered on the Y axis that I was rotating on. Thanks!